# How to set default values in getURLParameter(name) function?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
 }
 </script>
```

I then use the URL parameter in the jAlert pop up box as follows:

```
<script>
alert('Warning', 'Your'+getURLParameter('model') + 'is outdated.');
</script>
```

How can I specify that if URL Parameter name is for example, "Generic" or "Undefined", set it to some default parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the input parameter name?, or return value of the function

Comment: Add an if statement to check if name is !name then set it to something

Answer (score 0):

This checks whether `name` param is set or not; if not, it gets a default value:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {

    if (!name)
        name = 'default Value';

    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `name = name || 'default value';`

is kind of idiomatic and will save you a few keystrokes (namely `if(!){}` against `||`).

It's not useful, and neither `if(!name){ name = 'default value'; }`, if you accept some of the many JavaScript's falsy values.

If you need to accept falsy values, below is the proper version for that is

- `if(typeof name === 'undefined'){ name = 'default value'; }` .

```js
function defaultArg(name) {
   name = name || '<strong>my default name</strong>';


   document.write("My name is " + name + '</br>\n');
}

defaultArg();
defaultArg(undefined);
defaultArg(false);
defaultArg(null);
defaultArg(0);
defaultArg("Peter");
defaultArg(1);
defaultArg('null');
defaultArg('undefined');
```

```js
function defaultArg2(name) {
   if(typeof name === 'undefined') name = '<strong>my default name</strong>';


   document.write("My name is " + name + '</br>\n');
}
document.write('</br>')
defaultArg2();
defaultArg2(undefined);
defaultArg2(false);
defaultArg2(null);
defaultArg2(0);
defaultArg2("Peter");
defaultArg2(1);
defaultArg2('null');
defaultArg2('undefined');
```